# replace value of each object inside array

Tags: javascript, json

I want to change the value of each objects inside the array. I want to do a `path.parse(name).name` on the `name object` inside of the `item array` and return this `array` with the new values

My array is like this :

```
[
  {
    "name": "core Test",
    "item": [
      {
        "name": "test/core/core.js",
        "item": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "users Test",
    "item": [
      {
        "name": "test/users/user.js",
        "item": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

here is my code :

```
array.forEach((element) => {
  const { item } = element;
  item.forEach((i) => {
    const { name } = i;
    const newname = path.parse(name).name;
    console.log(newname);
  });
});
```

The output i want is :

```
[
  {
    "name": "core Test",
    "item": [
      {
        "name": "core",
        "item": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "users Test",
    "item": [
      {
        "name": "user",
        "item": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: expected output is not clear

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: What is the logic behind changing `"name": "test/core/core.js",` to `"name": "core",`

Comment: Do you want to reassign the `name` parameter to the result of `path.parse()`? If so, why aren't you reassigning. it?

Comment: @brk because i need only the name of the file not the whole path

Comment: how do i know that `core` is the name of the file from this `"test/core/core.js",`

Comment: @brk with path.parse("file name").name

Comment: i["name"] =  path.parse(name).name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you your desired output

```
const path = require('path')

const datas = [
  {
    name: 'core Test',
    item: [
      {
        name: 'test/core/core.js',
        item: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'users Test',
    item: [
      {
        name: 'test/users/user.js',
        item: []
      }
    ]
  }
]

const transformedData = datas.map(data => {
  data.item = data.item.map(x => ({
    name: path.parse(x.name).name,
    item: x.item
  }))
  return data
})

console.log(transformedData )
```